# Difference between Custom and Convention

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the difference between **Custom** and **Convention**. For example:

> - It is a **custom** in India to give money as a blessing on marriages.
> - It is **conventional** in many societies that strangers being introduced handshakes.

The Wikipedia definition for a **convention** is *A convention is a set of agreed, stipulated, or generally accepted standards, norms, social norms, or criteria, often taking the form of a custom.*   So can we use these words interchangeably? If so, can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **custom** is about habit, something that happens a lot.  A **convention** is about agreement, that it is accepted, formally or informally.  Obviously many things are both customary and conventional.

You might say:

- He was **conventional** in many things, but it was his **custom** to have breakfast at noon.
- The **custom** was to tip a waiter, and he strictly followed the **convention** out of fear of being considered miserly.

OED:

> **convention** *n* II. Agreement, conventional usage.
>   **custom** A *n* 1 a. A mode of behaviour or procedure which is widely practised and accepted (and typically long established) in a particular society, community, etc.; a convention; a tradition.

Note that both words have other meanings as well.

Comment: ‘It is a convetion widely accepted to stand on arrival of judge in courtroom.' or 'It is a custom to stand on arrival of judge in courtroom to show respect.'  Which would be more effective and correct?

Comment: In most situations you'd say "It is the custom to stand on arrival of the judge."  or "It is customary to stand ..."

Comment: @jonathanjo..thanks for the answer. I think it is better to stick with customary. In most cases I think customary can take place of conventional. True?

Comment: @Sud "conventional" emphasizes the agreement aspect. A custom can be personal, a convention is always shared. But most customs are in fact shared, so often there is little differene in meaning. "Conventional" is oftne used to describe a person (or a situation) who is normal, even overly normal, the opposite of eccentric, It may imply "dull" or "conformist". The word "customary" is not used in this way.